# Analytics - active page - change url for group up

Tags: google-analytics

I have a custom dashboard where I have an real-time table.

This table shows what pages are seen by users which are now on website.

There are pages like `/checkout/xxxxx`.

If there are 2 users on `/checkout/xxxxx1` and `/checkout/xxxxx2`. In table appear both pages.

I want to see just one, like `/checkout` and at count of users 2.

Here is an visual example:

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not programming related may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can filter by regex `^\/checkouts` and look at the row with the total values ​​(which represents the aggregate of the pages that correspond to the regex).

However, it may be wrong to say that if page `/checkouts/xxxxx1` was viewed by a user and page `/checkouts/xxxxx2` was viewed by a user, the total of users is 2.

This is because it could be the same user, so the total could be 1 (so, you can know it look at the row with the total values).

Comment: I don't have total values. I have a `real-time` table with `active users` and `active page`. Which show me how much users are on specific page at this moment. If one user is on `/page1` and he go to `/page2`. At `/page1`, column `active users`, will decrease 1 and will increase 1 at `/page2`

Comment: I'm not sure if that result could be obtained, I would try the Real Time Reporting API https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/realtime/v3#queries